# Unable to import database (.sql file) from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a database (.sql format) which I'd exported from other machine in phpmyadmin. I am continuously getting this error.
[image]

phpmyadmin version: 4.2.7.1
php version 5.6

Comment: have you created first database "test",  or try in your script to create it first.

Comment: first need to create data base as **test** @Abhishek Kumar then try again your script

Comment: 1) If `database` created select it then import. 2) Create new `database.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new database before import sql file.
Just create a new database or select any database you've created before. Then import sql file.

Answer (score 1):

Before being able to add tables you first need to create a database and then say you're going to use this database to add the tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test`
USE `test`;
```

And then you can `CREATE TABLE`.